# How to find solutions and to graph this second order DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

1)find two non-zero solutions that aren't multiples of each other
2) sketch the direction field in the yv-plane
3) for each solution, plot both its solution curve in the yv-plane and its y(t) and v(t) graph

1)
$\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}+3\frac{dy}{dt}-10y=0$

$y(t)=e^{st}$

$s^{2}+3s-10=0$

$s=-5, s=2$

$y(t)=k_{1}e^{2t}+k_{2}e^{-5t}$ $k$ is a constant.

One solution is: $y(t)=3e^{2t}+2e^{-5t}$

another is: $y(t)=5e^{2t}+4e^{-5t}$

2)

The direction field is a saddle at the origin.

3) Here is where i am confused. Would the solution curve in the yv plane be graphs of $\frac{dv}{dt}=-3v+10y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=v$

or the graphs of the two solutions from part 1) on the same axis.

Comment: @evgeny can you please help!

Answer (score 3):

**Part 1:** In order to not confuse variable names, rewrite the system as:

$$Y''(t) + 3 Y'(t) -10 Y(t) = 0$$

Let $Y = y$, so

$$y' = v\\v' = 10 y - 3v$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = -5, \lambda_2 = 2$, with eigenvectors $v_1 = (1,-5), v_2 = (1,2)$.

This gives,

$$Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
        y(t) \\
        v(t) \\
        \end{bmatrix} =  c_1 e^{-5 t}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        -5 \\
        \end{bmatrix} + c_2e^{2 t}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

We will choose two different initial conditions to get two non-zero solutions.

For $IC1$, choose $y(0) = 0, v(0) = 1$, leading to

$$Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
        y(t) \\
        v(t) \\
        \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
        ~~~\dfrac{2}{7}~~ e^{-5t}~~ + ~\dfrac{5}{7}~e^{2t} \\
        -\dfrac{1}{7} e^{-5t} + \dfrac{1}{7}e^{2t} \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

For $IC2$, choose $y(0) = 1, v(0) = 0$, leading to

$$Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
        y(t) \\
        v(t) \\
        \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
        ~~~\dfrac{2}{7}~~ e^{-5t}~~ + ~\dfrac{5}{7}~e^{2t} \\
        -\dfrac{10}{7} e^{-5t} + \dfrac{10}{7}e^{2t} \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

**Part 2:** We have a critical point at $(v, y) = (0, 0)$ and it is a saddle point from the eigenvalues. Using several hand calculations (see [*Example 1*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PhasePlane.aspx)) for the slope field direction gives

[image]

**Part 3:**

If we parametrically plot $y(t)$ versus $v(t)$ for $IC1$ (red) and $IC2$ (purple) we have:

[image]

[image]

Lastly, we plot solutions for $IC1$ and $IC2$ onto the phase portrait:

[image]

Do you notice why the phase portrait is so useful from these two solutions shown on top of it?